# traits with colliding method names - how to work with?

Tags: php, traits, php-7.4

I have an `interface` in essence defining `getEscapedString()` which is implemented in a couple of different traits; the actual classes pick one of them. This looks something similar to (excuse typos as this is just an example and not c/p); similar for Layout_B, Layout_C etc.

```
trait Layout_A {
  abstract protected function getUnescapedString() : String;
  protected function getCSS() : ?String {
    return NULL;
  }
  public function getEscapedString() : String {
    echo sprintf('<td class="%s">%s</td>', $this->getCSS(), $this->getUnescapedString());
  }
}
```

Works fine. Different layout use different abstract methods (rather by fortune), but most of them implement `getCSS()`. Some classes overwrite this to implement their own style; however, this method is not part of the interface as an implementation can perfectly live without it.

Now there is the need to combine two of these traits into a single class (by concatenating the output):

```
class DoubleOutput {
  use Layout_A, Layout_B {
    Layout_A::getEscapedString as getEscapedString_Layout_A;
    Layout_B::getEscapedString as getEscapedString_Layout_B;
  }

  public function getEscapedString() : String {
    echo getEscapedString_Layout_A();
    echo getEscapedString_Layout_B();
  }
}
```

This causes a collision of getCSS() which I could resolve e.g. by adding this into the use-clause:

```
    Layout_A::getCSS insteadof Layout_B::getCSS;
    Layout_A::getCSS as getCSS_Layout_A;
    Layout_B::getCSS as getCSS_Layout_B;
```

Now the result runs fine *except* that both traits access `Layout_A::getCSS` or - if I overwrite the method within the class - both traits access the new implementation.

Is there any (nice) way to let `$trait::getEscapedString()` use the matching `$traig::getCSS()` method? Only way I can think of so far is to change the traits to:

```
trait Layout_A {
  abstract protected function getUnescapedString() : String;
  protected function getCSS_Layout_A() : ?String {
    return NULL;
  }
  public function getEscapedString() : String {
    echo sprintf('<td class="%s">%s</td>', $this->getCSS_Layout_A(), $this->getUnescapedString());
  }
}
```

But this is really not good-looking and rather confusing for all usages of this trait except the double one.

Comment: I think this should be implemented with serveral classes not traits.

Comment: Hm. In reality these are something like Trait_Layout_Currency(), Trait_Layout_SimpleImage()..., each of them used in several classes to get the desired output format.

The new requirement came as one class should create *two* output columns which nobody has thought of before...

Comment: You say an “interface in essence”, do you mean a true interface or just a common pattern? It probably doesn’t matter, but you’re code didn’t include any `implements` so I wasn’t sure. I had a really hard time following your logic, so I wrote a demo, does this match your problem? https://3v4l.org/C2J1G

Comment: I think you’ve reached the limits for what you can do with traits. Since the contents of a trait are essentially copied and pasted into a class, code from a trait that accesses `$this` or `self::` can never be certain what code is actually going to be run, the class using that trait gets to decide this. I think you are going to have to duplicate code somehow. Maybe make a new trait with your logic duplicated but working as you expect.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I meant "(I have an interface) (in essence defining getEscapedString)", because in reality more methods exist; I tried to reduce the complexity to the relevant aspects.
Code duplication is indeed a possibility - just skipping the trait(s) for this new class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have serveral classes and their instances

```
class Layout_Currency;
class Layout_SimpleImage;
...

$layout_currency = new Layout_Currency();
$layout_simpleimage = new Layout_SimpleImage();
...
```

Like the traits, each of them outputs data in the desired format.

Now if you want to output Currency + SimpleImage with a single class, you could implement it like this:

```
class DoubleOutput {
    public function getEscapedString(){
         global $layout_currency, $layout_simpleimage;
         $layout_currency->getEscapedString();
         $layout_simpleimage->getEscapedString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yesss. I transformed the globals to instance variables, but this is *exactly* what I was looking for.